# How to initially place WPF controls on dynamic fullscreen application

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, wpf-controls

Alright, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this for my rather *unique* case. I have a fullscreen WPF application where controls are added to a `Grid` dynamically and the user is given the option to freely **move/resize** them. The controls can be individually moved or resized anywhere on the parent `Grid` but I have prevented them from overlapping via their `MouseMove` events. They also cannot be moved outside of their container. Since the app will be running on machines with different monitor sizes, I need to take that into consideration when making the original layout. I have an initial layout that I would like to use, but it would seem that I'm out of options:

I first tried using **rows and columns** *just* to (initially) place the controls that are added. This method places them correctly but becomes a problem when I need to move or resize the elements because the control is already *assigned* to a particular row and column. I could try to use this method and then remove any rows/columns after placing the controls, but I don't think that would work well.

I've also considered a **Viewbox**, but that's not practical in my case for fairly obvious reasons (as it merely resizes the controls to fit the screen). I'd prefer not to use this because I would only need it to standardize my initial layout. That's it. I also don't want to mess up any text that will be displayed on the window.

So yeah, this is more of a "best practice" question because any solution I can think of would not look very professional or elegant. Feel free to ask any questions if you need clarification.

Edit: As an additional note, I'd prefer to stick with a `Grid` as opposed to a `Canvas` as my container.

Edit 2: Just to be clear, I would *not* need the specific (inital) layout **after the first launch**. When the program exits, the layout (Margins, Width & Heights, etc. for each element) is saved to a file to use for the next launch.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is a bit broad for Stack Overflow, and there's not enough detail here to provide a complete answer anyway.  For example, do you allow individual controls to be resized, or only entire rows/columns?  Do elements _have to_ be arranged in rows and columns, or can they be positioned anywhere?  If the latter, can they overlap?  etc., etc.

Comment: You could go first way, and to each element you add, you could assign row and column as middle one, add mousedown event, that will raise just one, then it will remove itself, and will set colspan/rowspan 999, col/row 0, and margin left/top as current position relatively to grid

Comment: @MikeStrobel Edited to add details. If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at multiple options, I've decided to just use a calculation to (sort of) simulate the behavior of rows/columns. Because my application is fullscreen, I can take my `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` and `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight` to orient my layout. Using a combination of universal padding (static values) and ratio-based calculations (dynamic values), I can smoothly set my initial layout.

For instance, I'm dividing the width of my monitor by `6` (rounded up to avoid decimals) and using that (minus half the control's width) as the control's `Margin.Left` property, centering it on a 'column' of sorts.

Honestly, my initial layout is fairly simple right now, so we'll see if this will suffice going forward. Thanks to everyone who contributed to the question, and sorry if I was unclear on what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

I've developed a number of kiosk/interactive applications using WPF. If you are trying to show the element transitions (while moving), then it might be best to use a parent Canvas and bind the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties. You can mimic the grid alignment, using a Canvas, if you put in place mechanisms (e.g. Manipulation/Mouse events, converters) to make sure that the Canvas attached properties adjust to the row/column offsets.

It is not uncommon at all to use the Viewbox to mitigate display differences (and your use case is not "rather unique"). You set the Viewbox to a target resolution (e.g. 1920x1080) and allow the control to fill the available space. The other alternative would be to dynamically apply a content template based on the application window size/ratio.

Comment: I've gone the Viewbox route to keep too much negative space from accumulating in a game UI.  Once the window size hit a width of 1920 or so, the Viewbox took over and scaled everything up.  It worked beautifully, especially on high DPI displays.  Like Eric says, it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do in full-screen applications.

Comment: Hmm... I _really_ wanted to avoid the Viewbox route because it doesn't scale text well and (as I said) I only need to establish a standard layout **initially** (meaning users can resize the controls themselves if they want it).

Comment: @Eric In a way, it is a slightly unique case. I just need to standardize a starting configuration for the UI elements. After the user exits the program, the current configuration will be saved and used for the next time (regardless of what's been changed).

Comment: @LukeDinkler, have you tried using TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" for the text?

Comment: Nah, I haven't used a `Viewbox` in ages. What would a dynamic content template look like?

Comment: @LukeDinkler, you can create a DataTemplateSelector that selects the correct template for the current dimensions/resolution. Check once at load and then respond to size changed events.

Comment: @Eric Interesting....If my layout is simple enough could I not just set it by calculating from `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`, etc. As in, dividing the screen height and width and placing the controls based on that?

Comment: @LukeDinkler, if simple enough that can work. I've used a custom CoefficientConverter in conjunction with screen size many times.